# Alert when exit button pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to make make an alert when the user clicks the exit `Button` in this activity. How can this be achieved?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, B.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                moveTaskToBack(true);
        });


    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are You Sure?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: The basics seem to be all in your code. Try to understand what you did, experiment a bit and you will get your result.

Comment: Totally agree with @AlbAtNf , look at the code under `onBackPressed()` there u create a alertdialog, use it for your exit button aswell.

Comment: You can make your question more specific if you want to get a clearer response

Answer (score 0):

Create a method called: `exitDialog()` like this:

```
public void exitDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are You Sure?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();
}
```

than use it in your `onBackPressed()` method and your exit button, like:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    exitDialog();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and

```
exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        exitDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Call on your button clicklistener your onBackPressed() methode !

And you would get the same alert like when you press the back key physical button !!!

```
exit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onBackPressed();

        }
    });
```